# Data Binding in DevExtreme Drop Down Box not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devextreme

Anyone using DevExtreme to create ASP.NET MVC project here? I just want to create a simple drop down box that bind data source come from the controller. Here is how it works inside the controller, I create a list of object, then I add the model having two fields "Key" and "Value" into the list. So I pass the list of object in return view in the controller. [image: screenshot]

As you can see from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VNOO.png) above while I debugging the View, the Model is the list of object that I passed in, it has data for sure. You can see there are two fields "Key" and "Value" from each item, and I also specified the ValueExpr and DisplayExpr. When I run the project, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUQds.png) is the result I get. I just don't know why it is still blank while my data does exist. Am I missing some code?[image: page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a little more detail it is tough to know for sure, but when I have run into this issue, I fixed it by checking:

- If the model was in the wrong format (Not a list/IEnumerable)
- The model class fields were set to private

I would also look at this link/demo DevExtreme has for SelectBox: https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/Widgetsgallery/Demo/SelectBox/Overview/Mvc/Light/

OR

DropdownBox: 
https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DropDownBox/SingleSelection/Mvc/Light/

Otherwise, this is what I use to fill my chosen editor (I am using Dapper for SQL call):

---

View

```
    @(Html.DevExtreme().SelectBox()
        .ID("DemoSelectBox")
        .DataSource(d => d.Mvc()
        .LoadAction("GetDemoData"))
        .DisplayExpr("DemoName")
        .ValueExpr("DemoValue"))
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetDemoData(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
    {
        List<DemoData> demoDataGrid= new List<DemoData>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            demoDataGrid= connection.Query<DemoData>(
                sql: @"SELECT DemoValue
                        ,DemoName
                        FROM DemoDatabaseTable"
                ).ToList();
        }

        return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataSourceLoader.Load(demoDataGrid, loadOptions)), "application/json");
    }
```

Model Class

```
public class DemoData
{
    public string DemoValue{ get; set; }
    public string DemoName{ get; set; }
}
```